# Enviando arquivos no Nginx erro "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo de `2MB` utilizando o Nginx, porem continuo recebendo o `413 arquivo muito grande`.

Versão: Nginx/1.4.6

SO: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 33, accepted):

É necessário fazer alterações no arquivo `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = <Tamanho Desejado>M
```

Em seguida alterar as configurações do servidor no Nginx. No arquivo  `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` ou no arquivo do seu servidor na pasta `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

```
server {
    client_max_body_size <Tamanho Desejado>M;
    ...
}
```

E por final, reinicie o serviço.

```
# service nginx restart
```

Aqui esta funcionando corretamente.