# Nginx não importa banco de dados no phpmyadmin: "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

eu tenho um banco de dados de 1,31MB
que estou tentando importar dentro do meu phpmyadmin,
que ao lado indica que suporta importar databases de Tamanho máximo: 2,048KB.

Mas, eu não estou conseguindo... toda vez que eu tento importar dá essa mensagem:

**"413 Request Entity Too Large"**

Comment: dê uma olhada aqui:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41619/enviando-arquivos-no-nginx-erro-413-request-entity-too-large/41623#41623

Answer (score 2):

Você deve setar a diretiva [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) para um valor maior, diferente do padrão de 1MB. A intensão dela é impedir que os clientes façam uploads muito grandes já que na maior parte dos casos comuns é apenas um formulário ou uma foto. Algo maior que 1MB seria suspeito, mas não no seu caso. Adicione isso ao seu arquivo de configuração:

```
client_max_body_size 5m;
```

Recomendo não por um valor muito alto aqui. Use o mínimo que servir para você.

Comment: Também é necessário alterar o limite do PHP, se não continuará dando o erro.

Answer (score 0):

É necessário fazer alterações no arquivo `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = <Tamanho Desejado>M
```

Em seguida alterar as configurações do servidor no Nginx. No arquivo  `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` ou no arquivo do seu servidor na pasta `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

```
server {
    client_max_body_size <Tamanho Desejado>M;
    ...
}
```

E por final, reinicie o serviço.

```
# service nginx restart
```

Aqui esta funcionando corretamente.

---

Resposta retirada [deste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41619/enviando-arquivos-no-nginx-erro-413-request-entity-too-large/41623#41623).